# Laravel File put permission denied on Windows

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to save a file in windows and find a problem with File Class,
When I upload a file i get this error:

> ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 111:
>   file_put_contents(./upload/Bambui/2016): failed to open stream:
>   Permission denied

and this is my function to save the file:

```
public function save() 
    {
        $input = Input::only('empresa','tipo','data','data_pub','deliberacao','status','num_registro','publicacao','arquivo'); 

        $diretorio = $this->atas->checkAndCreateDirectory($input['empresa'], substr($input['data'], 6, 4));

        File::put($diretorio, $input['arquivo']);
   }
```

I give permission to all users in my `wamp` folder to write and read also.

Comment: does that folder really exist?

Comment: try to uncomment "LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so" in "C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf" look for the file "httpd.conf".

Comment: yeah that exists in public folder

Comment: jeffrey that was uncommented, I comment save restart, uncomment restart again but the problem continues

Answer (score 0):

Thx for help, I found myself the answer and change the File class to Storage and did this

```
Storage::putFileAs('pdf/'.substr($input['data'], 6, 4), $input['arquivo'], $filename);
```

and works